# Access unique constraint in Grails through constrainedProperty

Tags: grails, constraints, grails-domain-class

I'm having issues accessing a unique constraint defined in a Grails domain. [Here's an example from the official Grails documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html) (slightly edited to have a unique constraint):

```
class User {
    String firstName
    String middleName

    static constraints = {
        firstName blank: false, nullable: false
        middleName unique: true, nullable: true
    }
}
```

On Grails 3.1.9:

This code works: `User.constrainedProperties.firstName.blank`

This code does not work: `User.constrainedProperties.middleName.unique`

I get this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: unique for class: grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty
```

Is there any way to figure out if this constraint is set, similar to checking if the "blank" constraint is set? Thanks

UPDATE: Here's what I get when I try and use the code suggested in the comments (blank vs nullable only difference). hasAppliedConstraint works fine, but getAppliedConstrait does not. I assume I'm making a dumb mistake somewhere?

```
Condition not satisfied:

User.constrainedProperties.middleName.getAppliedConstraint('‌​unique')
                                           |                          |
                                           |                          null
                                          [ConstrainedProperty@20344ed7User'middleName'middleNamemap['nullable' -> [NullableConstraint@4a2415c5true], 'unique' -> [UniqueConstraint@7115e8atrue]]]
```

Comment: See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/3fa286c53d674f1e25cce95661b1ae38aa31ca3b/grails-test-suite-uber/src/test/groovy/grails/validation/ValidateableTraitSpec.groovy#L116-L150

Comment: The way to do this will depend on which version of Grails you are working with.

Comment: Ah yes, I should've specified my Grails version is 3.1.9

Comment: Something like `User.constrainedProperties.middleName.hasAppliedConstraint('unique')` will tell you if the constraint is set.  Something like `User.constrainedProperties.middleName.getAppliedConstraint('unique').unique` would tell you if the value is `true` or `false`

Comment: If I go look at the docs (http://docs.grails.org/3.2.4/api/grails/validation/ConstrainedProperty.html), I don't see a UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT listed...

Comment: @railsdog That is because that constant doesn't exist in the source code: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v3.2.4/grails-validation/src/main/groovy/grails/validation/ConstrainedProperty.java#L116-L131

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I get a NullPointerException when trying this `User.constrainedProperties.middleName.getAppliedConstraint('‌​unique').unique`. Am I doing something dumb? The hasAppliedConstraint works as expected, but I would also need to know whether its true or false.

Comment: It works for me if the constraint has been applied.  Sorry I can't help more.  Best of luck!

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Ok well thanks for everything so far. I must be doing something stupid somewhere... Anyone know why hasApplied works but getApplied does not on the same class?

Comment: What does this return ? User.constrainedProperties.middleName.appliedConstraints.find { 
          it.name == 'unique'
        }

Comment: @CagatayKalan I get `MissingMethodExceptionNoStack`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what eventually worked for me. Not sure why.

```
User.constrainedProperties.middleName.getAppliedConstraints().find {it.name == 'unique'}.properties.parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works because `User.constrainedProperties` returns `Map` with keys `domainPropertyName` and values `ConstrainedProperty`. In your case you are gets `ConstrainedProperty` of property `middleName` which has method `getAppliedConstraints()` which returns all constraints applied to `middleName`.

Better you can:

```
User.constrainedProperties.middleName.getAppliedConstraint('unique').parameter
```